# C# Collection of string constants used in the entire solution, HOW?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently making a windows phone app and I'm just looking at a sample from Microsoft for background audio on WinRT. 
The Solution has three projects, Lets call them P1,P2 & P3
In P1 there is a separate class file called constants with a collection of strings as shown in a cut below

```
 namespace BackgroundAudioPlayerCS
   {
    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of string constants used in the entire solution. 
    /// This file is shared for all projects
    /// </summary>
class Constants
{
    public const string CurrentTrack = "trackname";
    public const string BackgroundTaskStarted = "BackgroundTaskStarted";
}
```

in P2 & P3 there is also a file named constants except the Icon I different it says C++ with a little blue arrow, but if you open P2 or P3 constants file it opens the P1 file.

I have tried to repeat this In my project with no look
In their app when you come to call a string ie CurrentTrack you don't need to write Constants.CurrentTrack in any of the projects where as mine is only accessible from the project it is in and using Constants.string.

Also the P1 is not referenced any of the other projects.

How is it done?

EDIT**

Link : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319

Comment: And why don't you put it in a lib and use the reference from all the projects?

Comment: but doesn't that make it uneditable ?

Comment: You can create a dll, with some common classes, and use these classes from several projects.  the classes can be changed but some changes (like in interfaces) require recompile of all the dependent projects.

Comment: Are you using C# or C++?  Two different languages.  Please adjust your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be solve in two parts.

**For the first part**, I don't understand how you could retrieve the value of any of these constants without passing through the `Constants` class. Normally, you would always need to retrieve the value by passing through ex.: `Constants.CurrentTrack` and unless you are within the `Constants` class you could never call `CurrentTrack` directly.

**For the second part**, this is easy. Create the `Constants` file in the *first* project and then, you just have to add the files within the *second* and *third* projects using the `Add-->Add Existing Item-->Add as Link` as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: Thats what i thought, have a look for yourself i've added the link to my question

Comment: Sorry I have just checked again they do use Contants.CurrentTrack I wasnt reading properly I must have crossed it with another string sorry

Comment: @JulieGrey in that case I think I answered your question :-)